# tic tac toe grid display in the terminal when using tdd with rspec and ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I am currently writing code for a game of tic tac toe. I am seeking some advice as to what is the best way to create a grid that will be displayed when the game is played with the command line. I was going to use a hash for the places and a multi dimensional array for the possible winning combinations.

```
@places = {
  "a1"=>" ","a2"=>" ","a3"=>" ",
  "b1"=>" ","b2"=>" ","b3"=>" ",
  "c1"=>" ","c2"=>" ","c3"=>" "
}


@columns = [
  ['a1','a2','a3'],
  ['b1','b2','b3'],
  ['c1','c2','c3'],
  ['a1','b1','c1'],
  ['a2','b2','c2'],
  ['a3','b3','c3'],
  ['a1','b2','c3'],
  ['c1','b2','a3']
]


def put_line
  puts "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
end

def put_bar
  puts "#############################################################################"
  puts "#############################################################################"
end
```

I think that where my greatest confusion lies is how to write this using a board_spec.rb and a board.rb

If anyone could give me any guidance on this it would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - are you planning on making Board a class? I would think a test would look like:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'tictactoe'

describe Board do
  it 'has a 3 x 3 grid' do
    board = Board.new
    expect(board.board[0].size).to eq 3
    expect(board.board.size).to eq 3
  end
end
```

to make your test pass you could do:

```
class Board
  attr_reader :board
  def initialize
    @board = [
      ['-', '-', '-'],
      ['-', '-', '-'],
      ['-', '-', '-']
    ]
  end

  def printb
    @board.each do |row|
      print "|"
      row.each { |cell| print "#{cell}|" }
      puts "\n-------"
    end
  end

end

board = Board.new
board.printb
```

Comment: yes this was the approach i had taken. I just cant get my head around how this will display a grid on the command line. Sorry i am quite new to ruby!!